# THREE.js: divide a mesh to parts

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is there a way to divide one THREE.Mesh into several meshes?

for example a mesh with 2000000 polygons into 2000 meshes with 1000 polygons?

Edit: I guess you can not save the exact same amount of polygons/vertices after "cutting" the original mesh, but approximation would be great as well.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and am leaning towards just changing my process to export as independent objects.

Answer (score 0):

Like having a sphere explode into 1000 mini spheres? 
Maybe write a function in JS that gets a mesh from the scene and then somehow retrieve the polygons if that is possible and divide them. Then make a loop that creates new meshes with the values  you got from the math equasion and remove the mesh you used with

```
 "scene.remove( object);"
```

And add the new Meshes in the old Mesh's location with randomized x,y,z coordinates

Edit:

Maybe look at these examples:

https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_particles_sprites

or

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry

Comment: It is not what i wanted to do. I would like to take an asymetrical mesh and "cut" it into pieces. @robertjuh